# What is the name of this kind of plot for comparing pairwise differences in ANOVA?

Tags: anova, data-visualization

Hello I was curious if this kind of plot had a name. This is generated from SAS when doing Tukey's HSD to visualize which pairwise difference is significant. I quite like this visual but don't know what to call it for example learning how to make it in other software.

[image]

Comment: https://rpubs.com/brouwern/plotTukeyHSD2; https://r-graph-gallery.com/84-tukey-test.html; *etc.*

Comment: I don't know a name for that plot--it may not have one.  That said, it is a plot of the Tukey groupings.  Often older displays just presented letters.

Comment: Is it not a 'lines plot'? - see here: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/10/16/multiple-comparisons-lines-plot.html

Comment: If you replaced the colored lines with letters, it would be called a "compact letter display".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rho had it correct. SAS refers to this kind of plot as a lines plot. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/10/16/multiple-comparisons-lines-plot.html

The term I was unfamiliar with was Tukey grouping.